# Selecting a Color Selector

Tags: windows, software-rec, colors

I'm looking for a nice full featured color selector program, i currently use Color Cop but i feel its missing some features (mainly a nice interface for selecting a color from a spectrum). Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Which OS? Guessing Windows from Color Cop?

Comment: Yup. (comment length)

Comment: editing your tags or question would have been even faster (and clearer) ;)

Comment: Related question (to pick a color from the screen only, not a duplicate, so): http://superuser.com/questions/52755/good-color-picker-tool-that-runs-in-the-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [**ColorPic**](http://iconico.com/colorpic/), mainly for picking a color in an application but you can also select a color using various methods:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Colorbox](http://pourpre.com/colorbox/indexen.php) is a simple and powerfull software which make you able to select exactly the color that you want, the color of one pixel, etc